# Shorthand Expression

Tags: c, expression

What is the shorthand for this kind of expressions :

`X = Y < Z ? Y : Z`

Like, in case of 
`X = X + Y`
it can be written as,
`X += Y`

Comment: That _is_ the shorthand expression for an `if else` statement.

Comment: @Oli 
`if(Y < Z) {
    X = Y
} else {
    X = Z
}`

Comment: @MrMisterMan: Oh I see what you mean.  Yes.  I thought you were suggesting that `?:` was the shorthand for `if-else` in general.

Comment: @Oli Yes, I suppose `?:` isn't exactly analogous to `if else` but for intents and purposes this is why it's used.

Comment: @MrMisterMan: I consider things like `cond ? doSomething() : doSomethingElse()` extremely bad style.

Comment: @Oli I tend to agree. If it's instantly clear what you are doing with the `?:` syntax I think it's ok but otherwise it makes things harder to follow.

Comment: IMHO, the `?:` operator is inappropriate when it's just a shorthand for an equivalent if/else.  For example, using it as a top-level expression in an expression statement is just terseness for the sake of terseness.  It's ok when it's a subexpression of some larger expression *and* using `?:` makes the code more straightforward.

Answer (score 6):

There isn't one (at least not in standard C).

Define yourself a `MIN` macro!

```
#define MIN(a,b) (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))
```

(Be careful how you use this, macros are pretty dumb.)

Comment: Even C++ will work. As far as I remember, I have seen it somewhere but, can't recall :(

Comment: @SITZ: I believe GCC has the non-standard `<?` operator (or something like that).  But don't use it.

Comment: @SITZ: In C++ we have a `min` template in `<algorithm>` header

Comment: @Armen: It was just an example. Can there be made a shorthand for the type of ones I provided ?

Comment: @Armen, @SITZ: Read Scott Meyers' article on the subtleties involved in defining a universal `min` template: http://aristeia.com/Papers/C++ReportColumns/jan95.pdf.

Comment: @SITZ: No, it can't. And even if there existed some syntactic trick, why do you care? Write readable code